# Merging data with the same index and deleting data without the same index

Tags: python, pandas, merge

dataFrame 1:

```
index                    col1 
03-05-2018 12:00:00         3   
03-05-2018 13:00:00         4    
03-05-2018 14:00:00         3       
03-05-2018 15:00:00         3  
.......                    ..
```

dataFrame2

```
index                   col2 
03-05-2018 12:00:00        1    
03-05-2018 13:00:00        3    
03-05-2018 13:30:00        4    
03-05-2018 14:30:00        2    
03-05-2018 15:00:00        3   
.....                     ..
```

I want to merge these dataframes and delete the values where the indexes don't match:

dataFrame 3:

```
index                    col1 col2 
03-05-2018 12:00:00         3    1  
03-05-2018 13:00:00         4    3   
03-05-2018 15:00:00         3    3  
.........                  ..   ..
```

Is there a function like pd.merge to achieve this? (it's a pandas dataframe and the indexes are DateTime objects)
Thanks!

EDIT: I used pd.merge(dataFrame1, dataFrame2, how = 'inner', on='index', left_index=True, right_index=True) and I got the error "Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'int". I'm really sure both of the indexes are timestamps

Comment: Are your dataframe pandas, pyspark, or something else?

Comment: `pd.merge(df_1, df_2, how = 'inner')`

Comment: I tried your approach, it did work, however I ended up with more values (expected a number approximately around 55000, but I got 523916715)